# Ridiculous situation : Xcode changes elements frame if I just open storyboard files. I did nothing

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode 6.2 (Xcode 6.3 has same problem) at the moment. I've got some ridiculous situation when I just click to open storyboard files in the project navigator.

Xcode changes **frame** of elements in the storyboard file. I just open the file, I did nothing. See below screenshot. It's my diff screen. I shot this just after open a storyboard file.

[image]

Those changes are just tip of the iceberg. There are tons of unexpected changes.

I have no idea the reason why? and how can I fix it?

I'm scare opening storyboard files. I'm gonna die if this is persist.

Comment: did you update frames and save it after you assign constraints to the view?

Comment: I have seen similar behaviour and it is annoying - I often discard changes before committing if I know I didn't change the storyboard file, *but* as long as your constraints are set correctly it should all be good at runtime

Comment: @Katoch I can't remember exactly. Maybe yes Maybe no. The behaviour that you mentioned can be a reason?

Comment: @Paulw11 But I have to change something the storyboard file and the problem is it's not good even runtime. One of UITableView is getting smaller.

Comment: @DanielKIM Its not the exact solution to the problem you mentioned. That's why I commented instead of posting the answer. You will come across this problem for tableview / collectionview cells only.. I just update the frames to solve this issue.. It will work fine if you assign constraints to the views in cell accurately..

Comment: @DanielKIM Then your constraints aren't correct.

Comment: @Katoch Alright, you meant if I update frames and AutoresizingMask (I'm not using Autolayout) properly it would be fine. I'll try it. But if you're right I don't understand why Xcode change the frame even if I'm wrong something.

Comment: I really hate apple for making the autolayout an even worse nightmare.

Comment: i have the same problem, and some views can't be update frame!!!

Comment: I guess this situation happen when copy scenes from another storyboard files. Once copy a scene then open again I could see that happen only copied scene. But it happens not always.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. Every time I open storyboard after it has been closed it will re-arrange many of my frames. I can leave it and it will be good at runtime, but if I want to change anything I have to spend 10 minutes putting everything back where it should be. WTF Apple?

Comment: Issue exists also in Xcode 7.2 ;)

Comment: It is a known issue, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5900245/1356559).