# Why is git adding useless auto-changes for storyboards, what do they mean and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: swift, xcode, git, storyboard

Whenever I enter a `storyboad` in `Xcode` `git` ads some chage to those files that looks like this in `SourceTree`:

[image]

My questions are as in the title:

- Why are these chages added?
- What do they mean?
- How do I get rid of them? (in git ignore I suppose)

They are annoying as I always need to discard the chages to they don't cause unnecessary conflicts.

Comment: There aren't useless if there are really changes. The color changed. It has sometimes changes of frames (because of the "device previewer" change), and or "versioning" of the xib/Storyboard, and these I don't commit them.

Comment: It's not git that's adding/making those changes. It's an Xcode problem, it's Xcode that keeps making those changes, and it's a long-standing issue with Xcode always modifying the Storyboard file. I don't use Xcode anymore, but here are old related posts: [Xcode changes unmodified storyboard and XIB files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13233181/2745495), [How to avoid Xcode gratuitous edits to storyboard files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5900245/2745495)